# Placing the contents from s3 to my file system?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3cmd, s3fs

I have been trying to push the files in s3 to my ec2 instance.

When I do so :

```
sudo s3fs -o allow_other -o default_acl="public-read" files /home/logs
```

It doesn't give any error. But when I tried to look into the `logs` directory. I couldn't able to see any output at all!

Where I'm making the mistake? Are there any log file generated by `s3fs` command? So that I can look them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/439334/directories-are-not-mounted-by-s3fs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with s3fs but assuming its a file system driver, I would check dmesg.